# CVS2GIT migration failed - fatal: mark :6885 not declared

Tags: git, cvs2git

i was trying to run git fast-import using dump.dat file but got an error like fatal mark not declared.

**[root@linuxbuild spa-linux.git]# git fast-import --export-marks=../git-tmp/git-marks1.dat<../dump.dat
fatal: mark :6885 not declared
fast-import: dumping crash report to fast_import_crash_27128**

does someone can help me to resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

Should you be using `--import-marks` (not `export`)?

See [CVS2GIT- Conversion: Error "mark ... not declared" when running git fast-import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54113497/cvs2git-conversion-error-mark-not-declared-when-running-git-fast-import)