# CVS2GIT- Conversion: Error "mark ... not declared" when running git fast-import

Tags: git, migration, cvs, cvs2git

I'm trying to migrate an old cvs repository to git using `cvs2git` and `git fast-import`. The Export seemed to work fine, at least i did not notice any error messages. However, when i try to import the Dump files into my git repository with

```
git fast-import --export-marks=C:\temp\git-marks.dat < C:\temp\git-dump.dat
```

i get the following error:

> fatal: mark :52 not declared

This is the generated crash report:

```
fast-import crash report:
    fast-import process: 17584
    parent process     : 1
    at 2019-01-09 14:52:10 +0000

fatal: mark :52 not declared

Most Recent Commands Before Crash
---------------------------------
  commit refs/heads/master
  mark :1000000000
  committer loc\drst <> 1299577179 +0000
  data 16
* M 100644 :52 build.properties

Active Branch LRU
-----------------
    active_branches = 1 cur, 5 max

  pos  clock name
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   1)      0 refs/heads/master

Inactive Branches
-----------------
refs/heads/master:
  status      : active loaded dirty
  tip commit  : 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
  old tree    : 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
  cur tree    : 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
  commit clock: 0
  last pack   : 


Marks
-----
  exported to C:\temp\git-marks.dat

-------------------
END OF CRASH REPORT
```

So what does mark :52 mean and how can i find out whats wrong about that?

Comment: Marks are part of a programming language that `git fast-import` executes. Read [the `git-fast-import` documentation](https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-fast-import.html) for more. It sounds like cvs2git has a bug: it's generated a bad program.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, well my mistake was that i obviously needed to **import**, not **export** the previously created marks file :P The following statement seemed to worked perfectly:

```
git fast-import --import-marks=C:\temp\git-marks.dat < C:\temp\git-dump.dat
```